# Concurrent information. Sinatra or Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sinatra

I'm building a new web application that will hopefully be used to serve geo information from a MongoDB database.

The information will be delivered in JSON and HTML format.  Basically HTML for front facing web searches and JSON for API requests.

I'm new to Node.js but I am really liking it.  I'm also a Rails 3 developer by night so Sinatra is familiar to me.

Anyway, I hope to serve a lot of concurrent requests and my first instinct is Node but I found it difficult to get working with Mongo.  Not impossible but it wasn't as nice as Mongoid.

Any suggestions or tips would be appreciated on which platform to go.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to go with whatever you are more comfortable developing and deploying on. I'd personally go with Sinatra, but that's because I personally find it fast and elegant to develop with. If speed is critical, and more important than development time, you'll need to develop a reasonable benchmark on both and test it on both.

Answer (score 0):

Going with Phrogz here, do what ever you feel comfortable here - by the time you'll get enough traffic to feel the difference (if ever) you'll have enough data and experience to go on another choice if necessary.

just keep in mind that Node.js is running always as a single process and on a single core - so requests will be handled one by one.